# JSON + Spring 3.1

Tags: json, spring, rest, spring-mvc, collections

Hi I am trying to write small app with REST Json. I have some method that returns ArrayList of entity objects. And I am doing that:

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/workers/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public @ResponseBody ArrayList<Workers> showAllEmployes() throws Exception 
 {
     ArrayList<Workers> workers = new ArrayList<Workers>();
     workers = (ArrayList<Workers>) spiroService.getAllWorkers();
     return workers;
 }
```

And after this I got:

```
HTTP Status 500. The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
```

When I try to return primitive data type then all is ok. I have nothing in server logs. And I have necessary imports. Please some tip.

Comment: Do you get a Stacktrace with a more detailed error message in the server log/console?

Comment: Please post the Workers class as well!

Comment: Did you have the jackson jar on your dependencies / classpath?

Comment: which message converters have u used? and is ur Workers class properly annotated for ur messageConverter like jackson json annotations if JacksonJsonConverter is used etc. ? also try capturing more log turning org.springframework.web to DEBUG in ur log4j.xml

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have issue in produce json format, try this.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/workers/", method = RequestMethod.GET, 
                produces={MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
```